# Craft 2: get default user group from user settings

Tags: templating, settings

In Craft 2, I know I can [get general config settings](https://docs.craftcms.com/v2/templating/craft.config.html#properties).

How can I get the current **Default User Group** (set in Settings > User Settings) for use in my templates?

Comment: I'm not sure there's a native way of doing this. Do you need the group handle or the ID?

Comment: The group handle would be great.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this via a small plugin that provides you with a [template variable](https://docs.craftcms.com/v2/plugins/variables.html). I've made you a [working example here](https://github.com/olivierbon/gdug) with usage example.

It's a main plugin class with the basics then a [variable class](https://github.com/olivierbon/gdug/blob/master/variables/GdugVariable.php) that fetches the group `id` from your settings and retrieve the `handle` associated to that `id`.

I'm sure there are other ways to do this but that's one. Download, change... Make it yours :)

Comment: Wow, thanks so much Olivier :)